# How do I check that a number is in an array?

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table `T` one of whose columns is `pixels array<bigint>`. How do I check that a number is its element?

When I try

```
select * from T where 12345 not in pixels;
```

I get

```
FAILED: ParseException line 9:24 missing ( at 'pixels' near '<EOF>'
```

it appears that one can use `in` only with literal arrays.

what do I do?

Comment: @sds...what technology are you using?

Comment: @MikeTWebb: Apache Hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be [`array_contains`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions):

```
select * from T where not array_contains(pixels,cast(12345 as bigint));
```